# How to add/edit Label name in Panel of GEF

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am using Panel as a Figure in GEF eclipse. Now on double click I want to add a Label as other normal example shows .
How to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `EditPart` that manages the figure you should install a `DIRECT_EDIT_ROLE` policy (implemented by `DirectEditPolicy` class). This will cause your `EditPart` to be called when double clicks occur on the figure. The framework will call method `performRequest` with a `RequestConstants.REQ_OPEN` or `RequestConstants.REQ_DIRECT_EDIT` request. Upon receiving the request you can add whatever you want to the figure and refresh visuals.

If you want to edit text inside a `Label`, you can see how I implemented this [here](http://www.vainolo.com/2011/07/07/creating-a-gef-editor-%E2%80%93-part-7-moving-elements-and-direct-editing/).

Good luck.